# Flutter clipping issue with Stack inside of Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following code:

```
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(color: AppColors.LIGHT_BLUE, height: 75),
              Positioned(
                  top: 50,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Center(
                      child: _buildAvatar(
                    Provider.of<AuthService>(context).getLoggedInUser(),
                  ))),
            ],
          ),
          Text(user.displayName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
        ],
      )
```

which results in the Positioned avatar being clipped:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Is it incorrect to put a Stack inside of a Column like this? Or, do I need to wrap the Stack in something else?

Comment: what is your expected final result? The avatar resides in the appbar? or both in appbar and body ? I also noticed, Text its outside the stack, so it may covers the Circle Avatar

Comment: I wanted the avatar to reside in both the appbar and body. I think I'm starting to realize now that because the avatar is only inside of the stack, it cannot exist on top of elements outside of the stack. I guess a solution could be to add another widget to the stack to increase the height of it?

Comment: yes, I also have same idea. Maybe at the end, your Stack will consist 3 children. First one must be the AvatarWidget to be on top. Second and Third is Appbar and Body content respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you put the image into your Positioned widget. Stack widget is used when you want to put some widget in front of a widget.

So i think it have to be like this

```
body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(url); // Image here
          Positioned(
              top: 50,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Center(
                  child: //Some widget front image (may be Text)
            ),
        ],
      ),
      ),
      Text(user.displayName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
    ],
  )
```

And I recommend you to use Expended widget with flex in your column so that you can divide it into many part with height of the part depend on flex.